# vuejs vuex run action from action in store

Tags: vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex

I am trying to call `fetchProfile` on login and `onauthstatechanged` but none of these work.

```
this.fetchProfile()

this.store.dispatch("fetchProfile")

this.$store.dispatch("fetchProfile")
```

Im at a mental loss on this one. Not even console.logs in the `fetchProfile` runs, no evidence of the function running.

```
      actions: {
    authAction({ commit }) {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        console.log("Auth Changed");
        if (user) {
          commit("setUser", user);
          this.fetchProfile();
        } else {
          commit("setUser", null);
          commit("setProfile", null);
        }
      });
    },
    signInAction({ commit }) {
      console.log("Signing In");
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(response => {
          console.log("got response");
          commit("setUser", response.user);
          this.fetchProfile();
          console.log("fetch?");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          commit("setError", error.message);
        });
    },
    signOutAction({ commit }) {
      console.log("Signing Out");
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signOut()
        .then(() => {
          commit("setUser", null);
          commit("setProfile", null);
          sessionStorage.clear();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          commit("setError", error.message);
        });
    },
    fetchProfile({ commit }) {
      console.log("fetching");
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("profiles")
        .doc(this.getUser.user.uid)
        .get()
        .then(profile => {
          if (!profile.exists) {
            firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection("profiles")
              .doc(this.getUser.user.uid)
              .set({
                name: this.getUser.user.displayName,
                creationTime: this.getUser.user.metadata.creationTime
              })
              .get()
              .then(newProfile => {
                console.log("created user");
                commit("setProfile", newProfile);
                console.log(this.getProfile());
              });
          } else if (profile.exists) {
            console.log("User exists fetching profile");
            commit("setProfile", profile);
            console.log(this.getProfile());
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you get any error?
Can you create a codesandbox with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get access to `dispatch` from the first parameter, like `commit`.

This should work:

```
authAction({ commit, dispatch }) {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    console.log("Auth Changed");
    if (user) {
      commit("setUser", user);
      dispatch("fetchProfile");
    } else {
      commit("setUser", null);
      commit("setProfile", null);
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: Boom that was it! Thanks Irpe!

Comment: The weird part is it executes the first console.log but doesnt execute anything else. I have put console.logs everywhere and it never does anything else past firebase command

Comment: its like the firebase command never finishes or dies without error

Comment: Its definitely the firebase command causing it to never finish.

Comment: Is `getUser` a getter in your vuex code? You access getters like this: `this.getters.getUser`

Comment: ya it is, i swapped all of them to this.getters.getUser same for the this.getters.getProfile and no luck or error.

Comment: Then I'm stumped. Must be something in your firebase code, but I have no experience using that.

Comment: im dumb, i was doing this.getters.getUser.user.uid but getUser is the user...this.getters.getUser.uid worked...sorry for that

Comment: Yeah, I just wondered about that actually. Glad you figured it out.